# Copying address of char[ ][ ] to C-string

Tags: c++, pointers, char

The problem is I dont find a proper way to copy address of char[ ][ ] arr to string. Yep, i know it something about reinterpret_cast, but as far as I googled, I didnt find anything, except how to cout addresses, but nothing about copying.

To be more exact, lets say, I have char **arr, initialized it as

```
Hello

World
```

And now, I want to copy, for example, address of second letter of second word to some char[] string. How can I do it? Strcpy always complains no matter use I reinterpet_cast or  .

Thats how I created array :

```
char **arr;
arr = new char*[10];
char buf[100];
int i = 0;
while (gets_s(buf) && strlen(buf)!=0 ) {
    *(arr + i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(buf));
    strcpy(*(arr + i), buf);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to copy *addresses* or *characters*?

Comment: Ah, sorry, haven seen. I want to copy addresses of characters.

Comment: What do you mean with `I want to copy [...] address of second letter [...] to some char[] string` what is your expected output if you print that string you copied the address to?

Comment: I want to copy byte-adress of arr[i][j] to a char[ ] . As a result char[ ] must contain " 00B86...". Just imagine as we have integer matrix and want to get address of element and save it in char [ ]

Comment: @Tovarisch you cant copy an *address* into an array of *characters*. Only a *pointer* can be assigned an *address*. So, you need to clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish, because your description makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When populating `arr`, replace both occurrences of `*(arr + i)` with `arr[i]`, and replace `sizeof(buf)` with `strlen(buf)+1`.

```
char **arr;
arr = new char*[10];
char buf[100];
int i = 0;
while (gets_s(buf) && (strlen(buf) != 0) && (i < 10)) {
    arr[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
    strcpy(arr[i], buf);
    i++;
}
```

And don't forget to `free()` the allocated strings when you are done using them :

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    free(arr[j]);
}
```

But your question is tagged `c++` and this code is very C, not C++. The C++ way would look more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> arr;
std::string buf;
while (std::getline(std::cin, buf) && !buf.empty()) {
    arr.push_back(buf);
}
```

That being said, when you say you want to "copy, for example, address of second letter of second word to some char[] string", that makes no sense. You can't copy an *address* into an array of *characters*. The only thing you can assign an address to is a *pointer*, eg:

```
char *ptr = &arr[1][1]; // address of 'o' in "World"
```

If desired, you can then access other characters of the same pointed-to string via that pointer, using array like indexing, eg:

```
char ch = ptr[3]; // 'd' in "World"
```

Comment: Yep, i know, we are not allowed to use all C++ features, unfortunately. Still, I dont see here any solution, the problem is not in C-style for sure

Comment: Ty lad. I just wondered can I strcpy somehow this address to char [ ]. I understood your point, I should just initialise pointer as you described. Ty again.

Comment: @Tovarisch `strcpy()` copies *characters* from one `char` array to another. It has nothing to do with copying *addresses* at all. So either you are simply using the wrong terminology, or your understanding of how things work is fundamentally lacking.